# Is it possible to undo after Save/Closing a project?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, effects, illustrator-effects

I faced this problem just now, I added a drop shadow to my Logo to see how it's going to look and when I saved and sent the project to my friend, but I forgot to remove it or duplicate the original one (without the drop shadow), is there a solution for this (a way for me to remove a drop shadow)?

Answer (score 2):

Undo and Redo are not available after closing and opening.

However, the drop shadow and any other effects can be removed or adjusted in the Appearances panel.

Answer (score 0):

No. Once the document is closed the undo steps are purged.

The only way to recover a previous version would be through a backup system you have in place. You can't revert a document after it's been closed.